# transferring amount between saving and NRO

Tags: taxes, india, income

I want to transfer some amount from my mom saving account to my NRO account to pay my utility bills. I am managing my mother's account as she lives with me overseas. Will this amount will be taxable?

Comment: “she lives with me overseas” suggests that your mother may also be an NRI as per Indian law, and if so, she shouldn’t be holding an ordinary savings account in India; it should be converted into an NRO account also.

Answer (score 0):

From India taxes point of view, there is no taxes on this as parents can gift unlimited amounts to children.

Not sure if this would come under gift taxes in yourcountry of residence, it would depend on your tax status and regulations in that country.

Comment: could you please explain what you mean by "parents can gift unlimited amounts to children.?" Maybe with a link to a site that goes in depth on this?